# Backup of Mac OS X what files to backup

Tags: macos, mac, backup

I am using Mac OS X (Snow Leopard) and I am using Jungle Disk to back up all the data. I want to backup my calendar and address book. However I am not sure where the data really resides and what files to backup also.

Also I would like to backup iTunes songs including information like rating of a song and how many times I played that song. What files should I be backing up?

Answer (score 5):

Your address book is in

```
/Users/[your username]/Library/Application Support/AddressBook
```

It's the .abcddb file - be safe and backup the entire directory

Your calendar(s) are in

```
/Users/[your username]/Library/Calendars
```

Again, backup the entire directory

iTunes details are stored in the iTunes Music Library.xml file found in /Users/[your username]/Music/iTunes.  See [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1451) for some details.

Good luck

Comment: I would suggest backing up your entire User folder at least. If you are concerned about the amount of data you are uploading you can exclude specific folders (like your Movie and TV folders for iTunes for example). Be aware that backing up the iTunes Music Library does not backup your music, podcasts, etc. It only has the structure of your playlists, ratings, play counts etc. Since you have Snow Leopard you can use a hard drive to backup your entire computer very easily.

Comment: Agreed. It's probably best to just back up everything in your home folder.

Comment: Because it's so inexpensive anymore I tel everyone to buy an external USB harddrive and do regular backups with something like SuperDuper!